# Adding additional columns for a metadata driven copy task in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have a metadata driven copy task set up in ADF. The metadata is stored in a database. We wanted to add some additional tables that will also include the current UTC date as an additional column.

In a regular copy task, the syntax to do this is this:

```
        "additionalColumns": [
            {
                "name": "_IngestionDateUtc",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@utcnow()",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        ],
```

And I get the following results:
[image: Copy task example]

However when I add this to `CopySourceSettings` to the metadata tables, I get this error when running the pipeline:

> ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidValueInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'value' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Object must implement IConvertible.,Source=mscorlib,'

If I change the syntax to this:

```
        "additionalColumns": [
            {
                "name": "_IngestionDateUtc",
                "value": "@utcnow()",
                "type": "Expression"
            }
        ],
```

I get this instead:

[image: Second example]

What is the correct syntax for adding a date field or another expression for an additional column?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem for this behavior is **Meta data driven copy tool won't support dynamic content for the Additional columns** like normal copy activity.

[image]

You can only give a **custom value to the additional column but not a dynamic expression**.

```
"additionalColumns": [
            {
                "name": "_IngestionDateUtc",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@utcnow()",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        ],
```

The meaning of this `JSON` is adding a dynamic content for the copy activity.

**In Meta data driven copy tool, it will take the pipeline JSON from the control table and adds that JSON to the properties by dynamic content**. So, if you add the above JSON to the Meta data tool JSON, it will consider the first `value` object as the additional column value in the copy activity. But the **value should be a string but not an object and thats why it is giving the above error**.

Coming to your second `JSON`

```
"additionalColumns": [
            {
                "name": "_IngestionDateUtc",
                "value": "@utcnow()",
                "type": "Expression"
            }
        ]
```

This means adding `@utcnow()` as **Custom** value in the additional column like above.

But here, this JSON will be passed to the control table and the copy activity in the bottom pipeline will take the JSON from the control table. The dynamic content value in this JSON won't be calculated and it will be considered as a string value because the whole JSON will be taken as a dynamic expression. That is the reason for getting the additional column result like below.

[image]

You can observe the same in the copy activity input.

[image]

If the Meta data copy tool supports the dynamic content for additional columns, then it will give the proper result for you. You can raise a feature request about it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).

The temporary workaround for this is, you can add the value of `@utcnow()` from the JSON and add it to the additional column in both copy activities in the bottom pipeline.

Modify the additional column expression like below which won't change the incoming JSON from control table but adds the required time during the copy activity run.

```
@json(replace(string(json(item().CopySourceSettings).additionalColumns),'@utcnow()',utcnow()))
```

[image]

You need to add this expression for both copy activities inside the if condition of Bottom pipeline.

**This will give the desired result:**

[image]